# Conditional rendering of a static partial in react - MERN

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, conditional-statements

I am trying to figure out how to conditionally render a partial in react. My condition is that when a list item is active, the partial should be rendered.

I am using bootstrap, which has an active element available for use.

My goal is to achieve something similar to intercom's terms page: https://www.intercom.com/terms-and-policies#billing

In my main menu, I have:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

var Terms = require('../overview/terms.jsx');
var Privacy = require('../overview/privacy.jsx');
var Cookies = require('../overview/cookies.jsx');
var Thirdparty = require('../overview/thirdparty.jsx');
var Website = require('../overview/website.jsx');
var Sla = require('../overview/sla.jsx');
var Acceptable = require('../overview/acceptable.jsx');
var Billing = require('../overview/billing.jsx');
var Information = require('../overview/information.jsx');
var Incident = require('../overview/incident.jsx');
var Bug = require('../overview/bug.jsx');


class Menu extends React.Component {

render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className = "row">
          <div className = "col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 generalhead">
            Terms and Policies
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className = "row">
          <div className = "col-md-3 col-md-offset-1">
            <ul className="list-group">

              <a href="#" className="list-group-item list-group-item-action listitems" data-attribute = "terms">Terms of Service</a>
              <a href="#" className="list-group-item list-group-item-action listitems" data-attribute = "privacy">Privacy Policy</a>
              <a href="#" className="list-group-item list-group-item-action listitems" data-attribute = "cookies">Cookies</a>
              <a href="#" className="list-group-item list-group-item-action listitems" data-attribute = "thirdparty">Third Party Processors</a>
              <a href="#" className="list-group-item list-group-item-action listitems" data-attribute = "website">Website Use</a>
              <a href="#" className="list-group-item list-group-item-action listitems" data-attribute = "sla">Service Level Agreement</a>
              <a href="#" className="list-group-item list-group-item-action listitems" data-attribute = "acceptable">Acceptable Use</a>
              <a href="#" className="list-group-item list-group-item-action listitems" data-attribute = "billing">Billing</a>
              <a href="#" className="list-group-item list-group-item-action listitems" data-attribute = "information">Information Security</a>
              <a href="#" className="list-group-item list-group-item-action disabled listitems" data-attribute = "incident">Incident Response Plan</a>
              <a href="#" className="list-group-item list-group-item-action disabled listitems" data-attribute = "bug">Bug Bounty</a>

            </ul>
          </div>
          <div className = "col-md-6 col-md-offset-1">
             <Terms />
             <Privacy />
             <Cookies />
             <Thirdparty />
             <Website />
             <Sla />
             <Acceptable />
             <Billing />
             <Information />
             <Incident />
             <Bug />
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

module.exports = Menu;
```

Each list item has a named data attribute. When that attribute is the active item, I want to then render the partial. At the moment all of them are rendering.

I have read the react docs on conditional rendering: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/conditional-rendering.html

I was trying to define a const called active that I thought might make use of the bootstrap class - but that isn't working. I must have the wrong end of the stick for how to do this. I seems like a simple hide show for a rails js toggle. I can't figure out how to get started on tackling this in react.

Can anyone give me a steer in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep track of which list item is active in your state

```
<a href="#" onClick={() => this.setState({active: 'terms'})}>Terms of Service</a>
```

Then conditionally only render the active item

```
{this.state.active == 'terms' && <Terms />}
```

But I suggest using react router instead since each item seems to correspond to a page.

**Edit**

You have to add a constructor to your class to make it stateful

```
class Menu extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            active: false
        };
    }
    .
    .
    .
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried to use this suggestion. I think part of the problem might have been that i use extend React to create classes instead of 'create.class'. I changed the this statement to try to make sure the "this" binds, {this.state.active.bind(this) == 'terms' && <Terms />}. I get an error that says TypeError: Cannot read property 'active' of null

Comment: It has nothing to do with `extend React.Component` that just means you're extending the `Component` class that react provides. This is how you make class components. Or you could `extends PureComponent`. No need to `.bind(this)` to this.state.active. Unless you're storing a function there that you plan on using as a callback, but you would do the bind in the constructor of the class. You will need a constructor on your class and and to use `super` so that you have access to `this` and then set the initial state of the class. Read this  https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html

Comment: @KyleRichardson - thanks -If I try using FuzzyTree's suggestion, I get an error that says: TypeError: Cannot read property 'active' of null. Googling that error suggested the bind statement.  Can you see a bit of the overview has the relevant explanation?

Comment: Ok so I didn't provide an answer because your question is a little confusing to me. All of your 'list items' are anchor links. Is there a particular reason? Does clicking them navigate you somewhere? When you click on them do they load the partial? Or are they just displayed as active when someone happens to be on that url? Are the partials related to your url at all?

Comment: @Mel as Kyle mentioned you need to add a constructor to your class. see update

Comment: Thanks both. Yes- I'll learn to integrate redux next up. These are partials, rather than links. It's just that bootstrap with react needs them to be buttons, links or self styled css. I'm using a refs because the css is provided. Thanks again